# Why is a variable global when set with `read variable` inside a `while` loop, but local when set with `while read variable`?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

```
unset myVariable i;
while [ -z "$i" ]; do
    read myVariable;
    echo "myVariable : '$myVariable'";
    i=foo;
done;
echo "myVariable : '$myVariable'"
```

(the `unset` is there to allow replaying the command)

press any key + ENTER, you'll get :

```
myVariable : '[what you typed]'
myVariable : '[what you typed]'
```

The value of `myVariable` exists outside of the `while` loop.
Now try :

```
tmpFile=$(mktemp);
echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz' >> "$tmpFile"
while read myVariable; do
    otherVariable=whatever; 
    echo "myVariable : '$myVariable', otherVariable : '$otherVariable'";
done < "$tmpFile";
echo "myVariable : '$myVariable', otherVariable : '$otherVariable'";
rm "$tmpFile"
```

you'll get :

```
myVariable : 'foo', otherVariable : 'whatever'
myVariable : 'bar', otherVariable : 'whatever'
myVariable : 'baz', otherVariable : 'whatever'
myVariable : '', otherVariable : 'whatever'
```

The value of `myVariable` is lost when leaving the loop.

Why is there a different behaviour ? Is there a scope trick I'm not aware of ?

NB : running GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> while read myVariable; do
> ```
>
> The value of `myVariable` is lost when leaving the loop.

No, `myVariable` has the value it got from the last `read`. The script reads from the file, until it gets to the position after the last newline. After that, the final `read` call gets nothing from the file, sets `myVariable` to the empty string accordingly, and exits with a false value since it didn't see the delimiter (newline). Then the loop ends.

You can get a nonempty value from the final `read` if there's an incomplete line after the last newline:

```
$ printf 'abc\ndef\nxxx' | 
    { while read a; do echo "got: $a"; done; echo "end: $a"; } 
got: abc
got: def
end: xxx
```

Or use `while read a || [ "$a" ]; do ...` to handle the final line fragment within the loop body.

Comment: I've seen `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do process "$line"; done` to handle the no-trailing-newline situation

Answer (score -2):

> Because you're piping into the while loop, a sub shell is created to run the while loop. Now this child process has it's own copy of the environment and can't pass any variables back to its parent (as in any unix process).

In this case, the `done < "$tmpFile"` redirection forces bash to generate a sub-shell (as for pipe).

Quoted from [bash variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/124321/45318) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: there's no pipe

Comment: @glennjackman You are right, I added a clarification.

Answer (score -2):

Your second example uses a `while` loop that has a redirected input.

It reads using `< "$tmpFile"` and many shells create a sub-shell for this case. You could try to run this script with `ksh93`. `ksh93` does not create a sub-shell in this case.

In your specific case, the reason is completely different:

- in the first example, you read one line from the input
- in the second example, you read until `EOF` is reached

The `read` command reads the input, then splits the input at `IFS` characters and then assigns words to the variable arguments of `read`.

If there are more words than variables as parameters to the `read` command, the last variable gets a concatenation of the rest of the words.

If there are less words than variables, the other variables are assigned an empty value.

Since you hit `EOF`, you have no word read but one or more variable as argument to `read`. This causes all variables to get an empty value assigned.

So something happened that you did not expect: `EOF` causes the `while` loop to be terminated and you see no `echo` command from within the `while` loop but only the final `echo` command after the `while` loop in this `EOF` case.

This final `echo` now prints the variable content that was cleared from hitting `EOF`.

Comment: "many shells create a sub-shell for [redirection]" -- really? Do you have a reference for this? Neither bash nor dash create a subshell: `echo foo > file; echo $$; while read line; do echo "$$ - $line"; done < file`

Comment: **This case** means the while loop.

Comment: My example is bad: the shell substitutes all the variables including $$ before execution. Nevertheless, redirection does not imply subshell, I believe.

Comment: I checked the script again and added a final explanation. I hope this is a better explanation than in the other answer.

Comment: I know what you mean by "this case". But there's no subshell for a simple redirection. Using dash, compare (i) using redirection `strace -f dash -c 'printf "foo\nbar" > file; while read line; do echo "1: $line"; done < file; echo "2: $line"'` to (ii) using pipe `strace -f dash -c 'printf "foo\nbar" | while read line; do echo "1: $line"; done; echo "2: $line"'`

Comment: Check the original Bourne Shell to verify my statement. To be able to do that download and compile schilytools and check with `osh`. BTW since `osh` was the name of the Thomson shell on UNIX V7, the next release of the portable Bourne Shell will be called `obosh`.